# OutOfMemoryError : org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK

Tags: out-of-memory, jgroups

I have memory leak with jgroup replication and ehcache that makes an OutOfMemoryError.
We tried different configuration for CahceManager but we're running out of idea.
If someone already encounter the problem.

Packages versions :

- ehcache : 2.10.0
- ehcache-jgroupsreplication : 1.7
- jgroups : 3.6.6.Final

Leak identification :

`One instance of "org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK" loaded by "org.ow2.jonas.web.tomcat6.loader.NoSystemAccessWebappClassLoader @ 0xc172f9e0" occupies 829 313 120 (88,02%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment[]" loaded by "<system class loader>".`

`Keywords
org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK
org.ow2.jonas.web.tomcat6.loader.NoSystemAccessWebappClassLoader @ 0xc172f9e0
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment[]`

Ehcache configuration :

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
    properties="connect=UDP(mcast_addr=239.193.0.97;mcast_port=45570;bind_addr=<ip_eth4>;):PING:MERGE2:FD_SOCK(bind_addr=<ip_eth4>):FD_ALL(interval=3000;timeout=10000):VERIFY_SUSPECT(bind_addr=<ip_eth4>;timeout=1500;use_mcast_rsps=true):pbcast.NAKACK(use_mcast_xmit=true;retransmit_timeout=300,600,1200):UNICAST:pbcast.STABLE(desired_avg_gossip=20000):FRAG:pbcast.GMS"
    propertySeparator="::" />
```

[Shortest Paths To the Accumulation Point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBpCX.png)

[Accumulated Objects in Dominator Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6vuE.png)

Comment: No previous errors available in the logs ?

Comment: Could you check in a heap dump (on OOM) what's being kept in the Concurrent HashMap ?

Comment: I add images about what's inside the heap dump from mat

Comment: I didn't find any error in the logs that could be linked to the problem